# ObjectInputStream giving strange results

Tags: java, network-programming

Here is the code I am using.

Client:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Socket socket = new Socket("0.0.0.0", 5555);
    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("C:/Documents and Settings/Owner/Desktop/Client/README.txt");
    byte[] b = new byte[1024];
    int i = 0;
    i = in.read(b);
    out.writeInt(i);
    out.write(b, 0, i);
    out.flush();
    i = in.read(b);
    out.writeInt(i);
    out.write(b, 0, i);
    out.flush();
    out.close();
    in.close();
    socket.close();
}
```

Server:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(5555);
    Socket s = ss.accept();
    ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:/README.txt");
    int i = 0;
    i = in.readInt();
    System.out.println(i);
    byte[] bytes = new byte[i];
    in.read(bytes);
    i = in.readInt();
    System.out.println(i);
    byte[] bytes2 = new byte[i];
    in.read(bytes2);
    fos.write(bytes);
    fos.close();
    s.close();
    ss.close();
}
```

The file README.txt has ~2400 bytes in it. When I run this, the server outputs this.

1024

1869488225

It then throws a java.lang.OutOfMemoryError.

Can anybody tell me why it is reading 1869488225 instead of 1024?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you trying to read the data twice?

Comment: @Jeffrey It is sending two different blocks of 1024 bytes.

Comment: Yes, but if `README.txt` has 2400 bytes of text in it, 2400 - 2048 = 352 bytes of unsent data. You should use a loop to send your chunks of data

Comment: @Jeffrey That is what I was doing, and I was running into this problem. This code isn't the code I am using, this the isolated problem.

Comment: Ahh, just making sure. How many bytes of data are you reading from the server's end? It is possible that you are reading less than 1024 bytes into your array and that `readInt` is getting confused by the extra bytes left in the stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
in.read(bytes);
in.read(bytes2);
```

Here you are ignoring the return value of read and assuming that it fills the buffer. You should change `read()` to `readFully()` here, but in general you should never ignore a `read()` result. It can be -1 indicating EOS, or it can be any count from 1 up to the buffer size. If you inadvertently specify a zero length buffer it can even be zero.